# Python bind to ipv4/6 address, selenium or other http clients?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I have a VPS that has multiple IP's for ipv6 (since its cheaper these days, its quite common for VPS to offer).

I was wondering if python allows to be bound to a certain ipv6 or if there is even functionality for binding to ipv4 addresses.

I would like to test a firewall on a server project I am working on, to see with SeleniumIDE (or if you can suggest something else that might support this binding to a certain address) if I can successfully block a range of IP and allow another range.

Can this be done with the python executable under a Linux environment or can it be done programmatically in a script? Since SeleniumIDE relies on an actual browser, perhaps it must be configured within the browser (I use phantomJS)? or is there a python library that would make this more convenient (BeautifulSoup?)?

Comment: What is a VPS? You can bind Python sockets to a specific port and ip address.

Comment: VPS is a virtual private server. Many come with multiple ipv6 but just one ipv4. Anyhow, thought it would be useful for testing IP blocking. would I have to change the implementation of the seleniumIDE python webdriver?

Comment: What do you want exactly? Filter or block IPv6 addresses from using by selenium python library? Bind selenium to use IPv6 addresses only?